# I can not use command ping by user gpadmin(not root)

Tags: docker, ping, rancher

I can not use command ping by user gpadmin(not root)]

[image]

I can not use command ping by user gpadmin(not root, root can use ping) in rancher 2.0.4, but it works on local docker, the error is:

> ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted.

I tried ubuntu\centos etc., all of them didn't work. I also found and tried a solution like `chmod u+s /bin/ping`, but it still did not work.

I thought there may be a specific configuration in rancher(k8s) because both platform(rancher and local docker) use the same image, the only difference is between starting by docker-run and k8s-run.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What container image are you using? What kind of user privileges do you have in Rancher?

Comment: I used centos 7.4 and there were user root and gpadmin,  gpadmin is a normal user created by useradd -g gpadmin gpadmin, did you mean I need to give a specific privilege to user gpadmin? I am fresh, please fell free to tell me how to give it by useradd command~ Many thanks

Comment: I don't get what you did with the users. Did you add another user inside the container? I just tried running the container using image `centos:7.4.1708`, and ping command works. And obviously the default user I get when I execute the shell is root. What is your use case? If you give step by step instructions to recreate the problem, may be I can debug.